# Getting function parameters from Roslyn completion API

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I was trying to use Completion API for building Autocomplete feature. The results are coming correctly but I am not able to get the method signatures.
For example: If I type **"string."**, API returns me all the methods like **"Format"**,**"Compare"** but after **"string.Format("** it does not return all the possible method signatures like **Format(String, Object), Format(String, Object[])** etc. Can someone help me in achieving that

```
var expression = "String.";
var code = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           @"
                               Imports System

                               Sub Main(args As String[])
                                     Dim typeUnderInvestigation As String = {0}
                                End sub
                             ", expression);

var projectInfo = ProjectInfo.Create(ProjectId.CreateNewId(), VersionStamp.Create(), "MyProject", "MyProject", LanguageNames.VisualBasic)
                             .WithMetadataReferences(new[] 
                             {
                                  MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
                             });

var project = workspace.AddProject(projectInfo);
var document = workspace.AddDocument(project.Id, "MyFile.cs", SourceText.From(code));

// position is the last occurrence of "Guid." in our test code
// in real life scenarios the editor surface should inform us
// about the current cursor position
var position = code.LastIndexOf(expression, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) + expression.Length;

var completionService = CompletionService.GetService(document);
var results = await completionService.GetCompletionsAsync(document, position);
```